# Boost, allow only one thread of function

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I desire to allow only one thread of a function.  This is one solution:

```
boost::thread thr_check_task;
thr_check_task.interrupt();
thr_check_task = boost::thread(check_task);
```

In this example, the function will always interrupt before starting again.  The problem I have though is that I run out of threads on my CPU so I'm forced to detach them:

```
boost::thread thr (check_task);
thr.detach();
```

Is there another way to force only one instance of a function to run short of using a global variable of the function in use?  Thank you.

Comment: Only start it once? There'll be only one thread if you only create one thread.

Comment: How is `check_task` implemented? is it possible to add custom termination handling? For example if you perform a calculation in a loop you could set a global variable to invalid to terminate your loop.

Comment: @immibis I use an event handler, so multiple events can trigger this function to start (i.e. PLC_error)

Comment: @xinthose So? If you only want it to run once, only start it the first time your function is called...

Comment: @immibis I use a PLC driver, so that when the PLC is unplugged, it can cause multiple errors down the road, but I only want one instance to reconcile the issue

Comment: @xinthose What's an "instance"?

Comment: @immibis one instance of the function; I know that all boost threads are given a unique ID *boost::this_thread::get_id()*

Comment: @xinthose Well then only start one thread with that function...

Comment: @immibis I know, but my code gets complicated and I like it to correct itself

Comment: One simple approach is to start one thread that loops running `check_task`, and at the start of each loop it waits on a condition variable before looking for things to reconcile.  The event handler can notify the condition variable, causing that single thread to drop out of the wait and reconcile, or if it's not currently in the wait - to start a new check/reconcile action immediately the next time it goes to wait.  That's usually ideal.